# Conditional sum of rows regrouped by type

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have 3 columns:

BL = represents the number of the order, there is multiple rows by BL because orders have different products

ENTMVT: represent the sales ("610" means command has been sent)
SORMVT: represent the return ("700" means order has been billed, 610, order has been returned)

I want to keep only BL which ALLS arrows are "610" (in fact I want to see how many commands are totally return) to visualize in Power Bi but I didn't find a conditional sum function in power bi to do so (with the conditional column tool)

can you help me with this matter?

[image]

I try to add a calculated column as said, but M seems not to offer SWITCH function:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite simple, you have two options:

1. Create a calculated column where you define the status

```
Status = SWITCH(TRUE(),
   Table[ENTMVT] = 610 && Table[SORMVT] = 610, "Returned",
   Table[ENTMVT] = 610 && Table[SORMVT] = 700, "Billed",
   "Default Status")
```

And now you can use this column in any chart and apply filters on it, etc..

2. In your measure pass it as a filter

```
Count BL Returned = CALCULATE(COUNT(Table[BL]), Table[ENTMVT] = 610 && Table[SORMVT] = 610)
    
Count BL Billed = CALCULATE(COUNT(Table[BL]), Table[ENTMVT] = 610 && Table[SORMVT] = 700)
```

Comment: I have an issue when i try to set your first function:


"It is not possible to determine a unique value for the "ENTMVT" column of the "EXPBLLT1" table. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values, without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result."

Comment: the first one needs to be added as a column on the table, not as a measure

Comment: Yes, but there is no SWITCH function In M under power query? or there is something i don't understand right now

i edit my question for adding some image, not sure if i can add one in comment

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-tutorial-create-calculated-columns